# Google Play within my app

Tags: android, google-play

My app has the ability to allow the user to download additional apks from the Play store.

Is it possible to open a webview or another type of view that shows only the apks that are embeddable with the app?

I have other apps in the Play store that are not embeddable with this app, so need to make sure that these do not show within the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own list of links.

Every item in list can direct you to the specific apk in the store.